# SurfaceView becomes tranansparent onCreate and onDestroy

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-camera, surfaceview

I am using a SurfaceView to show a camera preview in my activity.
The SurfaceView is placed inside a fragment.

When this fragment is shown the Surfaceview is punching a hole in my activity,
letting the user to see whatever is behind my activity.

After the camera is fully loaded, everything is fine. But when I want to switch back to another
fragment the same thing happens.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks,
Shuky

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceViews have two parts, the "surface" part and the "view" part.

The "view" part is a transparent hole that gets laid out with all the other views.  All of the views are composited onto a single layer.  The "surface" part is a completely separate layer that is rendered behind the view layer.  It has the same position and size as the "view" part, but appears behind *all* views.

If you need the "view" interaction to be a bit less weird, and you're using API 14 or later, you can use TextureView for your Camera preview instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I discovered that the cause to my problem is setting android:windowIsTranslucent to true, do you know how can I solve it without changing this flag?